# Batch with multiple callout to get record

Tags: apex, batch, callout

Is it possible to create a batch class that makes x calls to take n records at a time and run the dml of these records? For example. I call the service. I read the first 200 records and do dml, then call the service again, read the other 200 records and run the dml.

```
global class BatchCallout implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful {

Integer successRecords = 0;
Integer errorRecords = 0;
Integer offset = 0;
Integer maxOffset;
Boolean stopCallout = false;
String endpoint;

global BatchCallout(Integer maxOff){
    maxOffset = maxOff;
}

global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
    if (offset <= maxOffset){
        //make callout
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
        req.setMethod('GET');                                                                                  
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint+'?offset='+offset); 
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        if (res.getStatus() == 200){
            Map<String,Object> results = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());

            //increment offset
            offset++;

            //make DML
            insert records
        } else {
            //make callout with same offset
            //reinvoke execute method ??? 
        }
    }
}   

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    System.debug('Records success: '+successRecords);
    System.debug('Records error: '+errorRecords);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be fine if each `execute` call does callout then DML:

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<SObject> records)
{
    // perform callout

    // perform DML
}
```

Each run through the method executes in a distinct transaction. However, if you try to further chunk the scope records, you need to make sure you do *all* the callouts before *any* of the DML.

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<SObject> records)
{
    // perform callout 1
    // perform callout 2
    // perform callout 3
    // perform callout 4
    // perform callout 5

    // perform DML
}
```

Comment: I added the code to my question. In my case, what should the start method return? The List <SObject> scope parameter in the execute method is also unused. I don't know if the problem is clear. The volume of data to be imported is around 40k and the web service returns 1000 records at a time. The offset is used to get next records.